# ListView Not Showing New Data

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

1. I recently transferred over my Android Project from Eclipse to Android Studio and changed the API to 21. I realize that I probably should have done this in 2 steps, but I've made lots of code changes since then, and it's too late to turn back the clock.
2. The Code was transferred by simply creating a new Android Project and copying over the files, and fixing settings when I got compilation errors.
3. Since doing #1, I haven't been able to get the data to load / refresh in the class that extends the ArrayAdapter.
4. There isn't any problem with the data, and the GetView method is being called for the relevant records, and I see the data being set to the views in the code. But, once the code finishes running, the ListView is still empty.
5. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Could anything have been messed up by transferring the code to AndroidStudio or changing the API to 21?
6. Is there anything else I should be checking in the code to make sure is running to diagnose the problem?
7. To be clear, before the transfer to AndroidStudio and change to API 21, the app worked perfectly, and as far as I know, nothing in this part of the code changed.

TIA

Comment: There is a lot of code. Which part of the code should I post?

Comment: Please check adapter, list item layout and theme and context you are passing to adapter.. 
Hope if data is binding correctly in adapter still listview can't render data after set adapter to list.. 
It can be minor theme/context/ui issue pl check with color changing of text or something like this

Comment: Are you refreshing adapter?

Comment: what method do you call to refresh the adapter?